# HTTP to HTTPS Redirect adds both URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, https

I'm doing work on a site that is mostly custom, and the HTTP isn't being redirected to the HTTPS correctly.

The site loads fine, but the HTTP version isn't redirecting properly, so it's showing as duplicate content.

I've looked at it a few different ways and I'm drawing a blank.

**Rewrite HTTP request for index.php to simply the domain name**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.*****.com [R=301,L]
```

**301 Redirect - redirect to index.php if web page is missing**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**Fix Canonicalization issue - add www on the HTTP request if it is missing**

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^insynergystl.com [nc]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.insynergystl.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

**Always use https for secure connections**

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.insynergystl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your https redirect to the top of the redirect list in the .htaccess, alternatively to your virtual host configuration itself.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

You can debug the redirects if you set the log level a bit higher, just don't forget to turn it off right after the part you are testing:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

**While you are testing make sure to only issue temporal redirects otherwise your browser will cache a redirect too and you will get redirected even if the code would no longer make you.**